# Oracle adf Addition issue

Tags: java, oracle-adf

Guys
I am making this simple Addition function in Oracle ADF
In which I am taking three input text fields first two for input numbers and third one for output and a button where i have written code for computing the addition operation.on a page after creating Adf Fusion Application in ADF
This is the code for

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <af:document title="PageAdd.jsf" id="d1">
        <af:form id="f1">
            <af:inputText label="input1" id="it1" binding="#{Mbean.input1}" autoSubmit="true"/>
            <af:inputText label="input2" id="it2" binding="#{Mbean.input2}" autoSubmit="true"/>
            <af:inputText label="output" id="it3" binding="#{Mbean.output}" autoSubmit="true"/>
            <af:button text="Submit" id="b1" action="#{Mbean.b1_action}"/>
            <af:selectBooleanRadio text="selectBooleanRadio 1" label="Label 1" id="sbr1"/>
        </af:form>
    </af:document>
    <!--oracle-jdev-comment:preferred-managed-bean-name:Mbean-->
</f:view>
```

As you can see the bindings. Mbean is the Managed Bean and the part after '.' is the property.
In the Button I have created this method called b1_action.
Below is the java code.
package view;

```
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.input.RichInputText;

public class Addition {
    private RichInputText input1;
    private RichInputText input2;
    private RichInputText output;

    public Addition() {
    }

    public void setInput1(RichInputText input1) {
        this.input1 = input1;
    }

    public RichInputText getInput1() {
        return input1;
    }

    public void setInput2(RichInputText input2) {
        this.input2 = input2;
    }

    public RichInputText getInput2() {
        return input2;
    }

    public void setOutput(RichInputText output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public RichInputText getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public String b1_action() {
        String s;
        String x;
        String v;
        s = (String)input1.getValue();
        x = (String)input2.getValue();
        int r2=Integer.parseInt(x);
        int r1= Integer.parseInt(s);
        int d =r2+r1;
        v =Integer.toString(d);
        output.setValue(v);        
        System.out.println(output.getValue());

        return null;
    }


}
```

While my Application is able to take the values and even add together but not able to display it in the third input text field which i am not able to do
I am new to this Tool and language Java kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

On your “output” component addd a partial trigger attribute like this:

```
<af:inputText label="output" id="it3" binding="#{Mbean.output}" autoSubmit=“true" partialTriggers=“ b1"/>
```

Comment: I removed the radio button it was a mistake

Comment: Partial trigger needs to point towards the id of your button. I edited the post, please check again.

Comment: I tried doing that i am getting an error as Java.faces.FacesException and java.lang.Nullpointer Exception after pressing the button

Comment: NullPointerException is an error in your code. If you can’t understand how to fix a NPE by yourself, probably you are not suitable do coding for living.

Answer (score 0):

First Make Input 1  and Input 2 `autoSubmit="True"`.
Then Make `partialTriggers="it1 it2"` for Output.
Make the `partialSubmit="True"` for the Button.

If nothing happend try to write  `this.output.setValue(V);`

Comment: Getting Java.faces.Faces Exception and Java.faces.el.evaluation.Exception,Java.lang.NullPointer.Exception

Comment: Sorry try to wirte   partialTriggers="it1 it2" instead of  PratialTriger="it1 it2"

Answer (score 0):

After `output.setValue(v);`

add this line of code 
`AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(output);`

Then set property `autoSubmit` to `“true”` inside output in your page